# draw randomly with exclusion restrictions

Tags: r

I want to randomly draw 5 numbers from a vector with replacement:

```
myvector <- c(1:50)
draws <- sample(myvector,5,replace=F)
```

However, want to include some restrictions.

*exclusion 1: I don't want to draw both 10 and 11 together*

*exclusion 2: I only want to have **one** of the following: 17,18,19,20.*

But each number should have the same probability to be drawn before the algorithm starts. My ideas so far violates this condition: assign the same number to the exclusions and draw from that:

```
myvector.wrong <- c(1:9,10,12:17,21:50)
draws.wrong <- sample(myvector.wrong,5,replace=F)
#say we draw a 17:
draws.wrong[1] <- 17
#then replace the 17 with a randomly drawn number from c(17:20)
draws.wrong[draws.wrong==17] <- sample(c(17:20),1)
```

However, this means that each number in c(17:20) now only has one fourth of the chance to be drawn compared to a number without restriction. I only want that chance reduced (to 0) once one number of the exclusions has been drawn with the same chance as any other. I could include 17 four times but then I risk drawing it twice which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Iteratively, this would be easier: after each draw check if any of the exclusion numbers are drawn (eg 10) and delete the corresponding exclusion numbers (10 and 11) before drawing again. However, I will carry out a lot (50k usually, sometimes 500k) repetitions of this process so efficiency is an issue.

Any takers?

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to check that your conditions are met and sample until you get a vector that you can use

```
check = function(x){
    if (sum(10:11 %in% x) > 1){
        return(FALSE)
    }
    if (sum(17:20 %in% x) > 1){
        return(FALSE)
    }
    return(TRUE)
}

a = 10:11
while(check(a) == FALSE){        
    a = sample(1:50, 5, replace = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought about this, too, but it is not efficient as I will draw a low of combinations which I will discard again. Also, aren't loops supposed to be slow in R? I really like the while idea though!

Comment: 50-500k in different runs.

Comment: @PeterPan, this is a good question. I can't think of a speedier solution though. Good Luck!